# Is there a way to convert the plot of an equation into the plot of an inequality using Canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, graph

I have some code that plots the equation of a graph in a coordinate plane. (Please see the comment below for the JsFiddle link that contains the code.) I'm trying to find a way to shade the region "less than" the equation, so that instead of plotting y = [equation], the graph depicts y < [equation]. It seems like this can be done for individual data points using "type:area" in canvas, but I'm wondering if this can be applied to the plot of an equation. I would greatly appreciate any help anyone can offer. Thanks!

```js
var x_axis = 200;
var y_axis = 200;

var x_max = 7; // THIS CHANGES RANGE OF X-AXIS
var y_max = 7; // THIS CHANGES RANGE OF Y-AXIS

var x_scale = x_axis / (x_max + 1);
var y_scale = y_axis / (y_max + 1);

var x_offset = x_axis + 0.5; // location on canvas
var y_offset = y_axis + 0.5; // of graph's origin

var canvas = document.getElementById("axes");
if (canvas.getContext) {
  canvas.width = x_axis * 2;
  canvas.height = y_axis * 2;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  drawAxes(ctx);
}

function drawAxes(ctx) {
  ctx.font = "20px";

  ctx.font = "14px";
  ctx.strokeText('Y', x_axis - 25, 10); //CHANGES LABEL OF Y-AXIS
  ctx.strokeText('X', x_axis * 2 - 10, y_axis + 20); //CHANGES LABEL OF X-AXIS

  ctx.font = "12px sans-serif";
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;

  // draw x-axis
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, y_offset);
  ctx.lineTo(x_axis * 2, y_offset);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  // draw arrow
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x_axis * 2 + 0.5, y_axis + 0.5);
  ctx.lineTo(x_axis * 2 + 0.5 - 8, y_axis + 0.5 - 3);
  ctx.lineTo(x_axis * 2 + 0.5 - 8, y_axis + 0.5 + 3);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();

  // draw x values
  j = -x_max;
  while (j <= x_max) {
    x = j * x_scale;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#aaa';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x + x_offset, y_offset);
    ctx.lineTo(x + x_offset, y_offset + 10);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.strokeStyle = '#666';
    ctx.strokeText(j, x + x_offset - 10, y_offset + 20);

    j++;
    if (j == 0) {
      j++;
    }
  }

  // draw y-axis
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x_offset, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(x_offset, y_axis * 2);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  // draw arrow
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x_axis + 0.5, 0.5);
  ctx.lineTo(x_axis + 0.5 - 3, 0.5 + 8);
  ctx.lineTo(x_axis + 0.5 + 3, 0.5 + 8);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();

  // draw y values
  j = -y_max;
  while (j <= y_max) {
    y = j * y_scale;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#aaa';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x_offset, y + y_offset);
    ctx.lineTo(x_offset - 10, y + y_offset);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.strokeStyle = '#666';
    ctx.strokeText(-j, x_offset - 25, y + y_offset + 5);

    j++;
    if (j == 0) {
      j++;
    }
  }
}

function offsetX(v) {
  return x_offset + (v * x_scale);
}

function offsetY(v) {
  return y_offset - (v * y_scale);
}

var canvas1 = document.getElementById("plot");
if (canvas1.getContext) {
  canvas1.width = x_axis * 2;
  canvas1.height = y_axis * 2;
  var ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");

  ctx1.lineWidth = 1;

  ctx1.beginPath();
  ctx1.strokeStyle = 'black';

  x = -x_max;
  y = x * x; // FIRST THING TO CHANGE TO CHANGE EQUATION (MUST USE * FOR MULTIPLICATION)
  ctx1.moveTo(offsetX(x), offsetY(y));

  while (x < x_max) { // INCLUDE CODE FOR BROKEN LINE IN HERE
    x += 0.1;
    y = x * x; // SECOND THING TO CHANGE TO CHANGE EQUATION (MUST USE * FOR MULTIPLICATION)
    ctx1.lineTo(offsetX(x), offsetY(y));
  }
  ctx1.stroke();
  ctx1.closePath();

  ctx.setTransform(0, 2, -2, 0, 3 * (y_axis / j), 3 * (x_axis / j)); // CHANGE LOCATION OF POINT; "3*(y_axis/j)" IS THE X-UNIT, SUCH THAT J IS THE MAXIMUM VALUE ON THE X-AXIS & 3 IS THE NUMBER OF INTERVALS FROM THE LEFT; "3*(X_axis/j)" IS THE Y-UNIT, SUCH THAT J IS THE MAXIMUM VALUE ON THE Y-AXIS & 3 IS THE NUMBER OF INTERVALS FROM THE TOP;
  ctx.arc(1, 0, 2, 0, Math.PI * 2)
  ctx.fill()
}
```

```css
body {
 margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
 position: relative;
}

canvas {
 left: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="axes"></canvas>
<canvas id="plot"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/huj7csta/32/

Comment: You can use `context.getImageData` to get and manipulate(!) every [x,y] pixel on the canvas. Test each pixel's [x,y] against your equation. *To graph less-than*: If a pixel equals the equation set its opacity to 255 (255==100%). If a pixel is less than the equation set its opacity to 64 (64~=25%). Otherwise leave the pixel transparent. Use `context.putImageData` to render your modified pixels back to the canvas.